# Copy outlook email content(have images , text , table etc) to microsoft word document

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I would like to use a outlook email for the message content. Lets say i have some formatted content containing images ,tables, colors, sizes, etc. Now I'd like to copy/paste all this content into an microsoft word document with proper alignment as same in the outlook email

Here is the code

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder subFolder = null;
            try 
           {
              app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
              ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
              ns.Logon(null,null,false, false);

              inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
              subFolder = inboxFolder.Folders[3]; 
              Console.WriteLine("Folder Name: {0}, EntryId: {1}", subFolder.Name, subFolder.EntryID);
              Console.WriteLine("Num Items: {0}", subFolder.Items.Count.ToString());

              for(int i=1;i<=subFolder.Items.Count;i++)
              {
                item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)subFolder.Items[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}", i.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", item.Subject); 
               // Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0} {1}" item.SentOn.ToLongDateString(), item.SentOn.ToLongTimeString());
                Console.WriteLine("Categories: {0}", item.Categories);
                Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", item.Body);
                Console.WriteLine("BodyFormat: {0}", item.BodyFormat);
                Console.WriteLine("HTMLBody: {0}", item.HTMLBody);
                Console.WriteLine("Attachment:{0}", item.Attachments.Count);
```

Comment: Microsoft outlook internally used MS Word interop editor to edit the contents of your email. You can directly use it save as you want.

Comment: I have already used interop and get all html but images are not there. Please provide code for achiving content to ms word document

Comment: Can you please post your code here ?

Comment: code is above.Thanks

Comment: heya, you just need to call SaveAs method of MailItem to save the contents to a doc file, like- **item.SaveAs("Your file path", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olDoc);**

Comment: I am using below code to copy all content from one word to another word file

Comment: var application = new MSWord.Application();                                      var originalDocument = application.Documents.Open("Sourcefile"); originalDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory(); var originalText = originalDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection; var newDocument = new MSWord.Document();              newDocument.Range().Text = originalText.Text; newDocument.SaveAs(destination file)

Comment: this code gives only text format not all html data like tables images

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor in Outlook. So, you can use the Word object model for modifying the body content or copying it in the existing Word document directly. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the Body of your email.

You can read about all possible ways of working with bodies in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) in MSDN.

Also you can save the item using the [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868727(v=office.15).aspx) method passing the olDoc value as a second argument.

Comment: I have save my outlook content in a word file. Now I want to copy some specific data from that word file to another ms word  file.

Comment: originalDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
                    var originalText = originalDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection;

                    var newDocument = new MSWord.Document();
                    newDocument.Range().Text = originalText.Text;